# Angular con universal renderiza dos veces la página

Tags: angular

Estoy usando angular con universal, pero la página se carga dos veces, la primera sin los datos de la API y la segunda ya los trae cargados

¿Alguien sabe cómo resolver este problema?

Esta es la forma en que hago solicitudes a mi API

```
getPagination(event, red=false) {
        if(red){
            this.router.navigate(['/eventos/'+event]);
        }else{
            this.events = new Array();
            this.loading = true;
            this.p=event;
            //if (this.events.length < this.totalEvents) {
                const filter = "ordering=startDate&items=" + this.pageSize + "&page=" + event;
                let urlfilter = '';

                for (let filter in this.filters) {
                    if(this.filters[filter] != ''){
                        urlfilter += '&'+filter+'='+this.filters[filter];
                    }
                }
                this.api.getEvents(filter + urlfilter).subscribe(res =>{
                    this.totalEvents = res['count'];
                    this.events = res['results'];
                    this.loading = false;
                }, err=>{
                    this.loading = false;
                })
            //}
        }
    }
```

Este es mi método en el servicio API

```
getEvents(where?: string): Observable<any> {
    where = (where) ? '?' + where : '';
    return this.http.get(this.apiUrl + `events/${where}`)
    .pipe(map(res =>  res), catchError(this.handleError));
  }
```

Lo que ocurre es parecido a esto:

https://media.giphy.com/media/3ohjUMI00mFB6GNZoA/giphy.gif

Comment: Puedes poner el componente completo o al menos un ejemplo minimo reproducible para poder mirar que es lo que ocurre? (Pd: el `map(res=>res)` de tu servicio puedes ahorrarlo que no hace nada :D)

Comment: @Narshe esto es lo que ocurre
https://media.giphy.com/media/3ohjUMI00mFB6GNZoA/giphy.gif